# iOS: Which one differentiates SOAP or REST

Tags: ios

I know about SOAP and Restful service usage on iOS development. SOAP can only use XML messaging but REST can use either. Using NSURLConnection initWithURLRequest Asynchronous call i can achieve working on both services, both can also use POST, GET and PUT. But, i would really to know how can we really identify whether my iOS code consuming SOAP or REST service, i got this doubt because even REST can also use XML messaging. Which is the one (code) really differentiates that i'm using SOAP or REST web service calls on my iOS program. Please someone clarify my doubt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use POST or GET on both (SOAP and REST services). It depends on what service does!
When the server provides SOAP services you have to manually create a soap envelope and add it to your request. It's kinda tricky and you should better go with REST whenever you can.

Also as you already mentioned, the SOAP responses are XML and REST supports JSON which is definitely easier to use in iOS!

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, let me know if you find any other differentiation apart from differentiate based on JSON usage.